# How to Know the Name of JPEG file when Saving PPTX file as JPEG?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, jpeg

I am using Presentation.SaveAs method to save PowerPoint presentation as JPEG files. However, I find there is no way to control the name of each JPEG file.

In English version, they are always named as "Slide1.JPG", "Slide2.JPEG", ...

In Chinese version, they are always named as "幻灯片1.jpg"， "幻灯片2.jpg", ...

It is OK for manual operation. However, for my program, how can it know and get the first slide image as its name is different on different computer system. It is impossible for my program to detect the locale and find out the actual name based on the locale as there are hundreds of them.

It is OK to save each slide one by one to control its name, with Slide.Export. However, that will decrease the performance if there are hundreds of slides.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Duplicate the ppt (Make a copy so that you won't destroy your original file if something happens)

Rename `Yourfile.pptx` to `Yourfile.zip` (Change extension to zip)

Extract the file (unzip)

You will get all image files used in it extracted with files and their real names.
In my case images were stored in `ppt\media` folder after extraction

I think same works for docx